# How does angularjs(v1) know when to start dirty checking?

Tags: angularjs

I know there is a watch list that angular will check each variable in.

But how the angular know when to start dirty checking?

If I changed a value on `$scope` object in angular world(controller), angular will start dirty checking.

But how the angular know I changed value on `$scope` object?

Angular2 uses rxjs while vuejs uses defineProperty.

How the angularjs work?

I want to know, is the dirty checking running all the time?

If not, when the dirty checking start or how the angularjs know it's time to start dirty checking?

Comment: you can manually call $scope.$apply() to start the digest cycle.

Comment: This should help: https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/

Comment: @Qing how you modify property on `$scope`? Directly - Angular will not notice that something changes. If you modify using some method like: $click, $timeout, $interval, $http - almost all method that are prepanded `$` internally executes `$rootScope.$apply()` and it starts `digest` for each child scope.